# Regex: Add space after a number when followed by letter

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

Following a set of numbers I would like to add a space to the string. For instance, the following strings should add a space after a number:

```
Before                           After
"0ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES"    "0 ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES"
"ABCD0 TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES"    "ABCD 0 TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES"

"ABCD 0TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES"    "ABCD 0 TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES"
"ABCD TECHNOLOGIES0 SERVICES"    "ABCD TECHNOLOGIES 0 SERVICES"

"ABCD TECHNOLOGIES 0SERVICES"    "ABCD TECHNOLOGIES 0 SERVICES"
"ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES0"    "ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES 0"
```

I have been trying to work on regex in Python as in the following way:

```
text= re.sub(r'([0-9]+)?([A-Za-z]+)?([0-9]+)?',
             r'\1 \2 \3',
             text,
             0,
             re.IGNORECASE)
```

With the previous code I am getting undesired spaces which are affecting other regex transformation:

```
"0 abcd     technologies     services   "
```

How can I get the addition of space in the string without adding undesired spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)', ' ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hrxq7c/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])` - a location between a digit and a char other than a digit and whitespace
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)` - a location between a char other than a digit and  whitespace and a digit.

[Python test](https://ideone.com/zOn7yr):

```
import re
tests = ['0ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES',
'ABCD0 TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES',
'ABCD 0TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES',
'ABCD TECHNOLOGIES0 SERVICES',
'ABCD TECHNOLOGIES 0SERVICES',
'ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES0']

rx = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)')

for test in tests:
    print(rx.sub(' ', test))
```

Output:

```
0 ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES
ABCD 0 TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES
ABCD 0 TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES
ABCD TECHNOLOGIES 0 SERVICES
ABCD TECHNOLOGIES 0 SERVICES
ABCD TECHNOLOGIES SERVICES 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :)

Comment: Easily extendable, just add dot to `\d\s`: `\d\s\.` and will match decimals too