# Regex in Python: Separate words from numbers JUST when not in list

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a list containing some substitutions which I need to keep. For instance, the substitution list: `['1st', '2nd', '10th', '100th', '1st nation', 'xlr8', '5pin', 'h20']`.

In general, strings containing alphanumeric characters need to split numbers and letters as follows:

```
text = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)', ' ', text, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

The previous regex pattern is separating successfully all numbers from characters by adding space between in the following:

```
Original       Regex
ABC10 DEF  --> ABC 10 DEF
ABC DEF10  --> ABC DEF 10
ABC 10DEF  --> ABC 10 DEF
10ABC DEF  --> 10 ABC DEF
```

However, there are some alphanumeric words that are part of the substitution list which cannot be separated. For instance, the following string containing `1ST` which is part of substitution list should not been separated and they should be omitted instead of adding an space:

```
Original            Regex                Expected
1ST DEF 100CD  -->  1 ST DEF 100 CD  --> 1ST DEF 100 CD
ABC 1ST 100CD  -->  ABC 1 ST 100 CD  --> ABC 1ST 100 CD
100TH DEF 100CD ->  100 TH DEF 100 CD -> 100TH DEF 100 CD
10TH DEF 100CD  ->  10 TH DEF 100 CD  -> 10TH DEF 100 CD
```

To get the expected column in the above example, I tried to use `IF THEN ELSE` approach in regex, but I am getting an error in the syntax in Python:

```
(?(?=condition)(then1|then2|then3)|(else1|else2|else3))
```

Based on the syntax, I should have something like the following:

```
?(?!1ST)((?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)))
```

where `(?!...)` would include the possible substitutions to avoid when matching the regex pattern, in this case the words `1ST 10TH 100TH`.

How can I avoid matching word substitutions in the string?

Comment: You misunderstand the word "conditional". The construct won't help. You may use negative lookaheads to restrict digit checking, like `(?<=(?!1ST\b)\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=(?!1ST\b)\d)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvn4NT/1)

Comment: Another idea: `re.sub(r'\s*(?!(?<!\d)1ST\b)(\d+)\s*', r' \1 ', text).strip()`

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew. It worked as a charm. Can you please recommend some regex books to learn in detail look arounds? I am still unsure to understand the details how the regex is processing step by step.

Comment: Do other answers help you or shall I post any of the solutions above with explanation?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, your solution worked, but I am kind of confused in the nested negative lookahead in the lookbehind.  I am trying to figure out how regex is going step by step to add space when is different to `1ST` and not adding space when is `1ST`.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot use spaces freely in the comments, could you please add that to the question? I understand `re.sub(r'\s*(?!(?<!\d)1ST\b)(\d+)\s*', r' \1 ', text).strip()` works, right?

Comment: Why applying similar regex `(?<=(?!12TH\b)\d{1,2})(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=(?!12TH\b)\d{1,2})` does not work for the string `WEST 12TH APARTMENT`. I am getting the message `{1,2} A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`. How can I make the regex suitable for situations such as 1ST, 10TH, 100TH, etc

Comment: So, the `python-regex` tag is not relevant? I thought you knew it means you are using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). `re` does not support unknown length matching quantifiers in lookbehinds.

Comment: I posted a full Python `re` based solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765443/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with exceptions, the easiest and safest way is to use a "[best trick ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)" approach. When replacing, this trick means: *keep what is captured, remove what is matched* or vice versa. In regex terms, you must use an *alternation* and use a *capturing group* around one (or some in complex scenarios) of them to be able to analyze the match structure after the match is encountered.

So, **at first**, use the exception list to build the first part of the alternation:

```
exception_rx = "|".join(map(re.escape, exceptions))
```

Note `re.escape` adds backslashes where needed to support any special characters in the exceptions. If your exceptions are all alphanumeric, you do not need that and you can just use `exception_rx = "|".join(exceptions)`. Or even `exception_rx = rf'\b(?:{"|".join(exceptions)})\b'` to only match them as whole words.

**Next**, you need the pattern that will find all matches regardless of context, the one I [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724657/3832970):

```
generic_rx = r'(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)'
```

**Finally**, join them using the `(exceptions_rx)|generic_rx` scheme:

```
rx = re.compile(rf'({exception_rx})|{generic_rx}', re.I)
```

and replace using `.sub()`:

```
s = rx.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) or " ", s)
```

Here, `lambda x: x.group(1) or " "` means *return Group 1 value if Group 1 matched, else, replace with a space*.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6665q7):

```
import re

exceptions = ['1st','2nd','10th','100th','1st nation','xlr8','5pin','h20', '12th'] # '12th' added
exception_rx = '|'.join(map(re.escape, exceptions))
generic_rx = r'(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)'
rx = re.compile(rf'({exception_rx})|{generic_rx}', re.I)

string_lst = ['1ST DEF 100CD','ABC 1ST 100CD','WEST 12TH APARTMENT']
for s in string_lst:
    print(rx.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) or " ", s))
```

Output:

```
1ST DEF 100 CD
ABC 1ST 100 CD
WEST 12TH APARTMENT
```

Comment: In the following expression `rx.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) or " ",s)`, x in lambda is getting the string for each iteration such as `1ST DEF 100CD`. However, if I try directly s.group(1) I am getting `str object has no attribute group`. What is this x in lambda if it is not the string coming from string_lst?

Comment: Why I cannot get the same result with text= re.sub(r'({exception_rx})|{generic_rx}',r'\1' or ' ', s)?

Comment: @Juan You cannot use a string replacement pattern because you need one replacement if Group 1 matches and another one if it does not.

Comment: I have reused the regex patterns in Postgresql. How can I get the same result without lambda? This is related to the first comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JuanPerez You can't do that in PostgreSQL, those functions do not support callback as replacement argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a lambda function to check whether the matched string was in your exclusion list:

```
import re

subs = ['1st','2nd','1st nation','xlr8','5pin','h20']
text = """
ABC10 DEF
1ST DEF 100CD
ABC 1ST 100CD
AN XLR8 45X
NO H20 DEF
A4B PLUS
"""

def add_spaces(m):
    if m.group().lower() in subs:
        return m.group()
    res = m.group(1)
    if len(res):
        res += ' '
    res += m.group(2)
    if len(m.group(3)):
        res += ' '
    res += m.group(3)
    return res

text = re.sub(r'\b([^\d\s]*)(\d+)([^\d\s]*)\b', lambda m: add_spaces(m), text)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
ABC 10 DEF
1ST DEF 100 CD
ABC 1ST 100 CD
AN XLR8 45 X
NO H20 DEF
A 4 B PLUS
```

You can simplify the lambda function to

```
def add_spaces(m):
    if m.group().lower() in subs:
        return m.group()
    return m.group(1) + ' ' + m.group(2) + ' ' + m.group(3)
```

but this might result in extra whitespace in the output string. That could then be removed with

```
text = re.sub(r' +', ' ', text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `regex`, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and `f-strings`:

```
import regex as re

lst = ['1st','2nd','1st nation','xlr8','5pin','h20']

data = """
ABC10 DEF
ABC DEF10
ABC 10DEF
10ABC DEF
1ST DEF 100CD
ABC 1ST 100CD"""

rx = re.compile(
    rf"""
    (?:{"|".join(item.upper() for item in lst)})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
    |
    (?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s])|(?<=[^\d\s])(?=\d)
    """, re.X)

data = rx.sub(' ', data)
print(data)
```

This yields

```
ABC 10 DEF
ABC DEF 10
ABC 10 DEF
10 ABC DEF
1ST DEF 100 CD
ABC 1ST 100 CD
```